# Custom FlatFileItemReader continues to read previous job state - not resetting linecount

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

In my case , Batch will start/trigger when a file watch listener gets a file and it will be processed. The file watch listener will again keep looking for next file .. when a new file comes - job will be triggered second time again ..

> From second job run (without stopping spring boot/Application)
>
> Flatfileitemreader is not reading the file from first line - because the line count and item count was not getting reset for flatfileitemreader,
>
> Its picking line count from where it left for the first job and it return null and job getting completed without processing.
>
> Example : If my first job text File has 2 records and second job text file has 2 records.
>               first file will get processed and flatFileItemReader linecount will be 2 and itemcount will be 2.
>               second file when comes - flatfileitemreader reads linecount as 3 and itemcount as 3 where there will not be no records and returns null and no records will be processed.

Any advice to handle this issue - Thanks in advance .

Added the code snipped of custom itemreader.

```java
    @Component
    public class UploadItemReader<T> implements ItemReader<T>  {

        @Autowired
        private Utility Utility;

        @Autowired
        private AdaptiveFieldSetMapper<?> adaptiveFieldSetMapper;

        private FlatFileItemReader<T> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<T>();

        private DetailsWrapper Detailswrapper;

        @Override
        public synchronized T read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
            System.out.println("Reader Thread ID : " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " Reader Thread Name : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            String Id = Utility.extractIdFromPath();
            Detailswrapper = getDetails(Id);
            flatFileItemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(Utility.getCurrentDirectory()));
            flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(this.getLineMapper());
            flatFileItemReader.open(new ExecutionContext());
            return flatFileItemReader.read();
        }

        public LineMapper<T> getLineMapper() {
            DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
            lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(Detailswrapper.getDelimiter());
            DefaultLineMapper<T> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<T>();
            lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
            lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper((FieldSetMapper<T>) adaptiveFieldSetMapper);
            return lineMapper;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your first run marked as complete ? In spring batch, if you start a new job with the same parameters, job will start where it stopped.

Comment: thanks for response @Degravef .. Everytime i am passing new job parameters only & my first run is marked as completed ..